# How to download a resource using https behind a proxy without using "rejectUnauthorized: false"?

Tags: node.js, networking, axios, proxy, fetch

I'm trying to download `https://www.stackoverflow.com` or `https://www.google.com` using [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) while I'm behind a [proxy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/tips.md#proxying)

I keep running into this error `RequestError: unable to get local issue` if `rejectUnauthorized: false` is not used. I know that this `rejectUnauthorized: false` workaround is a security issue.

`stackoverflow.com` and `google.com` must have trusted well-known CAs, so why am I getting this error?

```js
import got from "got";
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from "hpagent";

const result = await got("https://www.google.com", {
  agent: {
    https: new HttpsProxyAgent({
      proxy: process.env.https_proxy,
      rejectUnauthorized: false, // If true => RequestError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    }),
  },
}).text();

console.log("result:", result);
```

On the other hand, this request to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` works without setting `rejectUnauthorized: false`

```js
const result = await got("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", {
  agent: {
    https: new HttpsProxyAgent({
      proxy: process.env.https_proxy,
    }),
  },
}).text();
```

Can you please explain this inconsistency and how to resolve it?

*Note: I'm using Node.js 14.17.6*

Answer (score 0):

Try again, maybe it's fixed now, I'm using this lib passing certs options and seems to work fine for me.